# What is wrong with my AngularJS routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngroute

I've created an AngularJS sandbox, so to speak. I used the template html provided by Bootstrap for setup speed purposes, and I plan on using Bootstrap to fancy it up the fast way. While setting everything up, I noticed that my routes aren't working properly. In my `index.html` file, I've tried placing my angular file in several places, but I don't believe that's the issue. I've also tried using `<ng-view></ng-view>`, instead of using a `div`. In `app.js`, I've tried renaming the route to the templateUrl from the root directory to the end file, `app/home/home.html`, along with many other configurations. When I load in my browser, all I get is my navigation menu. I don't even get the html from the templateUrl. I may be wrong about all of this, but I can't figure it out. I've placed a generic Bootstrap navigation in my `index.html` file for my initial set up. What could be my issue?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Angular</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>



    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/home/HomeController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
      templateURL: "home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when("/about", {
      templateURL: "about.html",
      controller: "AboutController"
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/home"});
});
```

HomeController.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){

  $scope.noun = {
    person: "Maximus Aurelius",
    place: "World",
    thing: "sword"
  };

});
```

home.html

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello {{noun.person}}</h1>
</div>
```

My Directory

[image]

Dev tools network

[image]

Comment: I would try adjusting your template url file reference. If your templates are stored in a subdirectory then you need to specify what that directory is

Comment: I think @andrewdleach is right, please check your directories. Btw, I didn't know `<ng-view>` exists, but I may be wrong. If not, it's `<div ng-view>`

Comment: I just uploaded my directory. Take a look and suggest something. I've tried a few routes and I'm getting nothing. My console isn't even throwing an error, but I at least know that the `app.js` file is loading because the url is tagging on the `/home` after the index, as the routing states that it should.

Comment: Have you tried injecting `$locationProvider` into your `config` block and setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` ? You may also need `<base href="/index.html" />` in the `<head>` section of your index.html file.

Comment: it's 99% template issue, ui router can't know where your templates are, unless you are packing them up in some template cache under key by that name this will never work with that paths. add /home/home.html as template and /about/about.html

Comment: @Zooly ngView directive works on element or attribute. `<ng-view>` is perfectly valid and commonly used

Comment: @charlietfl ok I didn’t know tags were not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its just a typo in your $routeProvider.  templateURL should just be templateUrl.

Comment: I caught that and changed it. Still no luck.

Comment: made some other changes and put them in a plnkr.  looks like you were missing a line in your app.js. 

https://plnkr.co/edit/yElXqJ9S3YYiZeORMpxS?p=preview

Comment: It works in my plunk as well. Is there something that runs in the background on the plunker site? Are the files being served somehow? I ask because it's not working on my desktop editor. My files are now identical to to what is inside of the plunk. I've cleared the file cache. I have a very basic directory now. Although, I'm now throwing an error in my dev tools.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/ashtonl/Desktop/WestmanDocs/angularSandbox/home.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: I even left out the extra line you added and it still works in plunker. That tells me that plunker is running something that my computer is not. I have other AngulrJS app on my machine form developers that were using it before me. I can run an angular app from the others, but they have node modules installed. From my understanding, I thought that all you needed was the angular file or CDN if you're making a very simple angular app.

Comment: chrome won't let you do make a request to a local file like that.  you can use firefox or serve your files.

Comment: OOOHHHHHHHHhhh......well then. I think I found my issue. I googled that same concern and didn't find much. I only found how to install npm, which I already know. Thanks bud!

Answer (score 2):

The path to the templates is relative to the main page. You are looking for the templates in the root where the page file is but they are in subdirectories:

Try:

```
 $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
      templateURL: "home/home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when("/about", {
      templateURL: "about/about.html",
      controller: "AboutController"
    })
```

Comment: I tried that as well. I even did a copy and paste of your code. Still nothing. I was having a very similar issue when using routing on plnkr.co. Could the issue be something other than the routing?

Comment: Inspect the actual requests in browser dev tools network to see what status is

Comment: The network shows that it's loading the router, the controller, and the index.html, but not the home.html file. I'll post the screenshot I took. This is perhaps one of the most basic angularjs template/project there is. I've tried every directory configuration out there. I'm aware this could be a routing and directory issue, but I'm running our of tricks. I've even cleared my file cache.